# Play framework futures not being parallelised by default-dispatcher

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, akka, executioncontext

I'm trying to test the `ExecutionContext` behaviour in a play app, and found that I'm not able to achieve any degree of parallelism when I'm using the default dispatcher either by calling `as.dispatcher`, `as.dispatchers.lookup("akka.actor.default-dispatcher")` or passing the default execution context as a parameter to my Controller class:

```
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
```

I'm building on the play examples available in [here](https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.7.x/play-scala-hello-world-tutorial). And adding/altering the following configuration:

*routes*

```
GET    /futures    controllers.HomeController.testFutures(dispatcherId: String)
```

*common.conf*

```
akka {
  my-dispatcher {
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
    fork-join-executor {
      # vm-cores = 4
      parallelism-min = 4

      parallelism-factor = 2.0

      # 2x vm-cores
      parallelism-max = 8
    }
  }

  actor.default-dispatcher {
    executor = "fork-join-executor"
    fork-join-executor {
      # vm-cores = 4
      parallelism-min = 4

      parallelism-factor = 2.0

      # 2x vm-cores
      parallelism-max = 8
    }
  }
}
```

*HomeController*

```
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, as: ActorSystem) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  import HomeController._

  def testFutures(dispatcherId: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    implicit val dispatcher = as.dispatchers.lookup(dispatcherId)
    Future.sequence((0 to 10).map(i => Future {
      val time = 1000 + Random.nextInt(200)
      log.info(s"Sleeping #$i for $time ms")
      Thread.sleep(time)
      log.info(s"Awakening #$i")
    })).map(_ => Ok("ok"))
  }
}
```

For some reason, calls to `http://localhost:9000/futures?dispatcherId=akka.actor.default-dispatcher` (**default dispatcher**) don't parallelize and produce the following output:

```
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #0 for 1044 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #0
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #1 for 1034 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #1
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #2 for 1031 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #2
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #3 for 1065 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #3
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #4 for 1082 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #4
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #5 for 1057 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #5
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #6 for 1090 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #6
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #7 for 1165 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #7
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #8 for 1173 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #8
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #9 for 1034 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #9
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #10 for 1056 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #10
```

But calls to this `http://localhost:9000/futures?dispatcherId=akka.my-dispatcher` (using **another dispatcher**) parallelize correclty and produce the following output.

```
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #1 for 1191 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #0 for 1055 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #7 for 1196 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #4 for 1121 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #6 for 1040 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #2 for 1016 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #5 for 1107 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #3 for 1165 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #2
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #8 for 1002 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #6
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #9 for 1127 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #0
[info] c.HomeController - Sleeping #10 for 1016 ms
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #5
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #4
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #3
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #1
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #7
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #8
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #10
[info] c.HomeController - Awakening #9
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior is given by `akka.actor.default-dispatcher` that is of the type `BatchingExecutor` and this will try optimize in the cases of operations such as `map/flatmap` by executing them in the same thread to avoid unnecessary schedules . In the case where we are going to block we can indicate it with a hint as `scala.concurrent.blocking (Thread.sleep (time))` and in this way a mark is stored in a `ThreadLocal[BlockContext]` which indicates the intention to block and does not apply the optimizations but throws the operation in another thread.

if you change this line `Thread.sleep(time)` for this `scala.concurrent.blocking(Thread.sleep(time))` you will get the desired behavior

```scala
@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents, as: ActorSystem) extends AbstractController(cc) {
  import HomeController._

  def testFutures(dispatcherId: String) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    implicit val dispatcher = as.dispatchers.lookup(dispatcherId)
    Future.sequence((0 to 10).map(i => Future {
      val time = 1000 + Random.nextInt(200)
      log.info(s"Sleeping #$i for $time ms")
      scala.concurrent.blocking(Thread.sleep(time))
      log.info(s"Awakening #$i")
    })).map(_ => Ok("ok"))
  }
}
```

```
[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev) (no global state)
Sleeping #0 for 1062 ms
Sleeping #1 for 1128 ms
Sleeping #2 for 1189 ms
Sleeping #3 for 1105 ms
Sleeping #4 for 1169 ms
Sleeping #5 for 1178 ms
Sleeping #6 for 1057 ms
Sleeping #7 for 1003 ms
Sleeping #8 for 1164 ms
Sleeping #9 for 1029 ms
Sleeping #10 for 1005 ms
Awakening #7
Awakening #10
Awakening #9
Awakening #6
Awakening #0
Awakening #3
Awakening #1
Awakening #8
Awakening #4
Awakening #5
Awakening #2
```

Comment: You're right. Apparently both dispatchers (the default and the non default) have this same behaviour. The difference is that the controller uses a thread from the `default-dispatcher` and every future call using that same dispatcher from there without the `blocking` hint will cause this `batch` serialization because of the `ThreadLocal` flagging. Using another dispatcher for the future would cause the `batch` *not* to happen, since the http hadling thread is different. I believe that if I were to run futures from inside a thread of the other dispatcher the same would occur. Thanks!